Sporadic "File is being used by another process" when trying to open a file after copying to a network share
In our application we have an ASP.NET web server and an API server for taking on various jobs. In this particular workflow the user uploads a file that the Web server copies to a network share for the Job server to consume. The Job server is notified of this through a new row in an MSSQL table which it scans every second. Sometime this year during integration testing this flow began randomly failing with:
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\\a\\b\\c.xlsx' because it is being used by another process."
Locally DEVs and QA never had this issue, but I assume it's because their shared folders are placed on their respective work machines. When the shared folder is moved from the local file system to a network share, the same exception begins to appear.
I am able to reproduce on a random occasion with this short application:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string DestinationDirectory = "\\\\10.122.xxx.xxx\\Testing";

    var inputPath = args[0];
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(inputPath);
    var destinationPath = Path.Combine(DestinationDirectory, filename);

    Console.WriteLine(filename);

    Console.WriteLine("Copying the source file...");
    File.Copy(inputPath, destinationPath, true);

    Console.WriteLine("Opening the destination file...");
    try
    {
        using var _ = File.Open(destinationPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

If I run it with this batch script I hit the exception roughly 1 in 10 times.
@echo off

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    FileShareDemo.exe "C:\a\b\c\myfile"
)

myfile
Copying the source file...
Opening the destination file...
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\\10.122.xxx.xxx\Testing\myfile' because it is being used by another process.
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategyCore(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Nullable`1 unixCreateMode)
   at System.IO.File.Open(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at FileShareDemo.Program.Main(String[] args)


From my testing, it seems that the file gets locked for a tiny amount of time, hence the sporadic nature.
Issue present on .NET 6 and .NET 8.
It could well be a Windows related issue, but running this batch script:

@echo off

set file=myfile
set source="C:\a\b\c\%file%"
set destination="\\10.122.xxx.xxx\Testing\%file%"

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    echo Copying...
    copy %source% %destination%
    
    echo Reading...
    type %destination%
    REM powershell -command "Get-Content %destination% -Encoding byte -TotalCount 2"
)

which performs the same commands, does not trigger the error, so I'm led to believe it's .NET related.
I have tried to use the Handle utility from Microsoft to find all file associated handles before and after file open, but the application is too slow to register them.

Is there any antivirus that might scan files? Has there been any change to configuration for the network share host?

@JonasH AVs are non-invasive and don't deny access, at least that's how they're made, unless something changed this year. On our side after the host OS of the file share got various updates and upgrades the issue became more frequent. Unfortunately I have no info about the client's hosts. They did say it started happening with an application upgrade, which I just checked, jumped .NET version from 3.1 to 6.0, so perhaps something about file handling changed with later versions. Too many variables at play.

In my experience, closing a file and immediately reopening it, or trying to delete it, may fail, and I have seen this at least since .net 3.5. I have no idea if it is an AV issue, or some kind of synchronization problem. One approach is to just wait a few ms and try again.

@JonasH Thanks for the confirmation. We implemented a single 5 second retry earlier today and the issue is gone, QA reports. You may post this as an answer.

FYI, it's kinda bad to access server shares via IP because it typically forces less-secure NTLM auth.

It seems that something on Windows locks new files for the tiniest moment, and the solution to that, is to try accessing the file again after a short period. We put a 5 second delay, and the issue has been gone since.
